# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre UNION y UNION ALL?

Tags: sql-server

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `UNION` y `UNION ALL` en SQL Server?

¿Cuál tiene mejor desempeño?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UNION**
La instrucción `UNION` se utiliza para seleccionar los datos relacionados entre dos tablas. Las columnas tienen que ser del mismo tipo de datos. Solo se devuelven los valores **distintos**

**UNION ALL**
La instrucción `UNION ALL` es similar a `UNION` con la excepción que se seleccionan todos los valores.

Por lo tanto la difirencia principal entre `UNION`y `UNION ALL` es que `UNION ALL`no eliminará de la consulta los datos duplicados.

Con respecto al rendimiento `UNION` realiza un `Select DISTINCT`sobre los resultados por lo que `UNION ALL`devuelve los resultados más rápidamente (Comparen los planes de ejecución que agregué al final)

A continuación algunos ejemplos:

```
 DECLARE @Tabla1 TABLE (ColDetalle VARCHAR(10))
 INSERT INTO @Tabla1
 SELECT 'A'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'D'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'E'

 DECLARE @Tabla2 TABLE (ColDetalle VARCHAR(10))
 INSERT INTO @Tabla2
 SELECT 'A'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C'
```

**Pruebas:**

```
 /* UNION ALL */
 SELECT *
 FROM @Tabla1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *
 FROM @Tabla2
 Order by 1
```

**Resultado y plan de ejecución:**

[image: UNION ALL]

[image: Plan de ejecución UNION ALL]

```
 /* UNION */
 SELECT *
 FROM @Tabla1
 UNION
 SELECT *
 FROM @Tabla2
 Order by 1
```

**Resultado y plan de ejecución:**

[image: UNION]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

`UNION` elimina los registros duplicados (donde todas las columnas de los resultados son iguales), `UNION ALL` no.

Hay afectación de rendimiento al utilizar **`UNION vs UNION ALL`**, ya que el servidor de base de datos debe realizar trabajo adicional para eliminar las filas duplicadas, pero normalmente no desea duplicados (especialmente al desarrollar informes).

## UNION ejemplo:

```
SELECT 'foo' AS bar UNION SELECT 'foo' AS bar
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+
| bar |
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## UNION ALL ejemplo:

```
SELECT 'foo' AS bar UNION ALL SELECT 'foo' AS bar
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+
| bar |
+-----+
| foo |
| foo |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Traducido de la [misma pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/3200493) realizada en [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: Sí, de hecho es correcto que devuelva `foo`